# Check if post exists

Tags: php, mysql

So i want to check if a post exists in the database but i have some problems with redirection.
This is my work so far:

```
echo '<br>';//the $row part tells the DB what post his looking on
echo '<a href="comments.php?post_id='. $row['id'].'">View comments</a>';
```

This is the show comment button that leads to the section where you see the comments for the post.

---

```
<?php
require_once ('checkp.php');
```

I have it to require the post checking script once.

---

```
<?php
include ('variables.php');
//connects to DB
$dbc=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);


if ($dbc) {


 } else {

 echo ('Failed to connect to MySql; '. mysql_error());

 }


 //selects db from MySQl
 $sqldb=mysql_select_db('a2318052_blog');

 $pid=$_GET['post_id'];

 $query1="SELECT * FROM posts_b WHERE id='$pid'";
 $sql=mysql_query($query);

 if ($sql) {


 } else {

 echo "cant run query";

 }


 if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

 echo "that post does not exist!";

 } else {

 header ("location: comments.php?post_id='. $pid.'");

 }

 ?>
```

And this is the script that checks for a empty result and then redirects back. I believe its something with the redirect here (header ("location: comments.php?post_id='. $pid.'");)

Comment: You have a serious sql injection hole.

Comment: Why are you echoing that a post doesn't exist if you got results from your query?

Comment: that's a really good question

Answer (score 1):

You mixed the quotes on the redirect:

```
"location: comments.php?post_id='. $pid.'"
```

should be

```
"location: comments.php?post_id=". $pid
```

The dot in php is used to concatenate strings. Bu there you are opening the string with " and closing it with  '.

EDIT : Also as someone else already noticed you're using query instead of query1.
Also i suppose instead of:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

 echo "that post does not exist!";
```

you wanted something else:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {

 echo "that post does not exist!";
```

Comment: Or `"location: comments.php?post_id=$pid"`?

Comment: Well he was using points, so i guess he misunderstood how concatenation works.

Comment: Or he possibly got confused.

Comment: Mixing quotes in php... it can happen to everyone ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want single quotes around the post_id...

```
header ("location: comments.php?post_id=$pid");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM posts_b WHERE id='$pid'";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
```

You're using $query instead of $query1. That's probably the problem (along with the concatenation stuff other users have pointed out).

There's also a few other things, like I think you mixed up your if/else statement here:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {

 echo "that post does not exist!";

 } else {

 header ("location: comments.php?post_id='. $pid.'");

 }
```

Maybe you want the order to be reversed?

---

Also, you should look into avoiding SQL injection! 
Sending a query with a $GET variable is pretty dangerous, as users can manipulate the URL and send malicious queries.

```
$pid=$_GET['post_id'];
```

[Prepared statements are ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), but for now, you could use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) around your $GET variable. It stops people from sending queries you really don't want done.

Comment: It works now, but when i use the require_once it gets me in a redirect loop... Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I'm thinking you want to change the redirect to something else.
`header ("location: comments.php?post_id='. $pid.'");`
that line pretty much just keeps going to itself over and over. You get to comments.php?post_id=x, and then it sends you to it again, and again, loooped, if the comment is valid (and you've made the changes above).

Answer (score 0):

first change pid

```
$pid = intval($_GET['post_id']); // for security
```

after that

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{
    echo "that post does not exist!";
}
else
{
    header("Location: comments.php?post_id=".$pid);
}
```